# Union Operation of two string arrays - Java

Tags: java

I've two string arrays. For example `A = {"ABC", "XYZ", "MNO"}` and `B = {"ABC", "PQR", "XYZ"}` Now I want one string array having `{"ABC", "XYZ", "MNO", "PQR"}`

How can I do this? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)

```
String[] str={"abc","def","ghi"};
    String[] str1={"xyz","abc"};
    Set<String> set=new HashSet<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        set.add(str[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
        set.add(str1[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(set.toString());
```

Comment: Instead of looping, you can simply do a `set.addAll(array);`.

Comment: can you please show me some code??

Comment: not sure of array argument to addAll

Comment: @Balaswamyvaddeman, have a look at my example.

Comment: @Carlspring I like your example using existing API,What I feel basic arrays are very powerful than API

Answer (score 6):

Get a [HashSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashSet.html) and throw all your strings from both arrays in it. Sets do not allow replication so it will only have unique values. Once you are done, you could use the [Collections.toArray()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) to get yourself a string array as a result.

EDIT: It does not seem that you are after the way in which the elements are ordered, however, as per carlspring's suggestion, if you are, just replace the `HashSet` with a [LinkedHashSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html).

Comment: Make that a LinkedHashSet, just so you preserve the ordering.

Answer (score 2):

This is how to do it:

```
public class Foo
{

    public static String[] array1 = { "abc", "def", "ghi" };
    public static String[] array2 = { "xyz", "abc" };


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Using List: " + Arrays.toString(usingList()));
        System.out.println("Using Set: " + Arrays.toString(usingSet()));
    }

    public static String[] usingList()
    {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.addAll(Arrays.asList(array1));
        list.addAll(Arrays.asList(array2));

        return list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
    }

    public static String[] usingSet()
    {
        Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
        set.addAll(Arrays.asList(array1));
        set.addAll(Arrays.asList(array2));

        return set.toArray(new String[set.size()]);
    }

}
```

When using a `Set`, make sure you're using a LinkedHashSet, if you're expecting array-like ordering -- where the elements remain at the indices you've put them. `Set`-s tend to internally re-order elements, which might not be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I found a one-line solution from the good old Apache Commons Lang library. [ArrayUtils.addAll(T[], T...)](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#addAll%28T%5B%5D,%20T...%29). Code:

String[] both = ArrayUtils.addAll(first, second);

ex::  ArrayUtils.addAll(["a", "b", "c"], ["1", "2", "3"]) = ["a", "b", "c", "1", "2", "3"]

Comment: Yeah, good one, if you can use Apache Commons in your project. +1.